# Правила построения url в rest api

Tags: api, rest

У меня есть пользователи ( имя, фамилия, отдел) и отделы ( название отдела, ...). Пользователь может быть отнесен только к одному отделу. Для работы с пользователем реализованы следующие методы:

- GET /users - просмотр всех пользователей
- POST /users - добавление нового пользователя
- GET /users/id - просмотр конкретного пользователя
- PUT /users/id - полное изменение пользователя
- PATCH /users/id - частичное изменение пользователя
- DELETE /users/id - удаление

Подскажите какая должна быть структура URL для назначения сотрудника в отдел и удаление сотрудников из отдела? Может быть такая:

- POST /departments/{dep_id}/users/{user_id} - добавление пользователя
  в отдел или
- POST /users/{user_id}/departments/{dep_id} - добавление пользователя
  в отдел

Или вообще, работа с отделами должна вестись через изменение конкретного пользователя, т.е. передаваться в теле запроса PATCH /users/id ?

Answer (score 0):

По хорошему изменение отдела (добавление или удаление) должно быть в форме добавления/изменения пользователя, то есть для этого стоит использовать POST и PUT/PATCH.

Если ещё есть контроллер, связанный с самими отделами, то вариант

`POST /departments/{dep_id}/users/{user_id}`

тоже можно считать одним из вероятных, хотя и слегка более сложных, вариантов.

Comment: Если формой то да, я в контроллере получал объект User со встроенным в него объектом Department и заданным в нем поле id из <select>.  А если делать без интерфейса, чисто rest-api, то нужно же по такому же url делать, как если бы делали через браузер? Тогда выходит что "POST /departments/{dep_id}/users/{user_id}" вообще не подойдет. Запутался уже немного в этих best practices.